# Solution of equation are vertices of polygon

Tags: complex-numbers

the solution of equation $z^4+4z^3-6z^2-4iz-i =0$ (where $i=\sqrt{-1}$) are the vertices of convex polygon in complex plane.Find the area of the polygon.

How should we approach this question? Could someone give me some hint?

Comment: The roots are very hard to get

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of a trick question -- if I gave you an arbitrary polynomial and asked you to do the same thing then you'd have no chance of doing it by hand.  You have to recognize something special about this particular polynomial.  Do the coefficients remind you of anything?

Comment: Sorry but I can't observe anything special about the polynomial.

Comment: Do the numbers 1, 4, 6, 4, 1 ring any bells?

Comment: They are binomial coefficients of $(1+x)^4$ ?

Comment: Yes.  Although, looking at the signs and the factors of $i$, it looks like $(1+x)^4$ isn't quite what we want.  Let's compare to $(x+i)^4$ instead.  (Also, I'm guessing that was supposed to be $4 i z^3$ and not just $4 z^3$.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury So wouldn't that mean that area of polygon will be 0?

Comment: No, because your polynomal isn't *quite* the same as $(z+i)^4$.